# Remove last column in VIM

Tags: vim, edit

In VIM how would I remove the last column of a txt file.

```
1 2 3 4
x x x x
x x x x
```

I want to remove column 4

```
Result:
1 2 3
x x x
x x x
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this on the lines (either with `%`, as a selection, as movement commands...):

`s/ [^ ]*$//`

Explanation: The regular expression matches everything from the end of line to the last delimiter, and discards that.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this and it highlighted everything correctly but did not delete the last column, is there something I need to add to delete it?

Comment: that's strange, it did when I tried it. You have to select the lines you wish to edit, e.g. by Shift-V, then input the above commands.

Answer (score 2):

i think vertical visual selections are pretty handy too.

```
gg$<C-v>h3jx
```

You can easily delete any column(s) you want this way.

Answer (score 2):

The other option is to use vertical selecting [ Shift+V ] the last column then just delete it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compute the whole buffer, use the regular expression mentionned by thriqon

```
:%s/ [^ ]*$//
```

It's also possible to obtain the same result by running an external command in vim

```
:%! cut -d' ' -f1-3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a macro that removes the last column, then apply that to the entire file.

So go to the first non-header row, and run

```
qa$bld$^q
```

Which will start recording in register `a` a motion that will go to the end of the line, then back a word, right one character until the space, then deletes until the end of the line.

Now undo that change with `u`.

Now apply that macro to the entire file with

```
:%normal @a
```

This is really handy for removing a specific row in a csv file.

For instance, to remove the last row of a csv

```
qa$F,d$^q
:%normal @a
```

Or to remove the second to last row

```
qa$2F,dt,^q
:%normal @a
```

See `:help :normal`, `:help @`, `:help q`, and `:help :%` for reference.